# Different ways of defining primes

Tags: code-golf, math, decision-problem, primes

One of my favorite definitions of the prime numbers goes as follows:

- 2 is the smallest prime.
- Numbers larger than 2 are prime if they are not divisible by a smaller prime.

However this definition seems arbitrary, why 2?  Why not some other number?
Well lets try some other numbers will define n-prime such that

- n is the smallest n-prime.
- Numbers larger than n are n-prime if they are not divisible by a smaller n-prime.

### Task

The task here is to write a program that takes two inputs, a positive integer **n** and a positive integer **a**.  It will then decide if **a** is **n**-prime.
Your program should output two distinct values one for "yes, it is n-prime" and one for "no, it is not n-prime".

This is a code-golf question so answers will be scored in bytes with less bytes being better.

### Tests

Here are lists of the first 31 primes for n=2 to n=12 (1 is the only 1-prime number)

```
n=2: [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127]
n=3: [3,4,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127]
n=4: [4,5,6,7,9,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113]
n=5: [5,6,7,8,9,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113]
n=6: [6,7,8,9,10,11,13,15,17,19,23,25,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107]
n=7: [7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,17,19,23,25,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107]
n=8: [8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,19,21,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
n=9: [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,21,23,25,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
n=10: [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89]
n=11: [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,25,27,29,31,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89]
n=12: [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,41,43,47,49,53,55,59,61,67,71,73,77]
```

Comment: `n=6, a=15` is the first interesting test case.

Comment: @Neil Why do you consider that one interesting?

Comment: It's the first place where the non-pattern "a is n-prime iff n≤a<2n or (a≥2n and a is prime)" breaks down.

Comment: *"Numbers larger than 2 are prime if they are not divisible by a smaller prime."* - This definition allows any number to be prime. Maybe you want to say **iff** instead of **if**?

Comment: @ThePirateBay I don't mean the precise mathematical sense of the word if.  I am going to leave it.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It still appears that the n-primes are the same as the ordinary primes except for "a few" exceptions in the beginning. For example, the 10-primes includes the exceptions `10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 21, 25, 27, 35, 49` (and of course the 10-primes miss the ordinary primes `2, 3, 5, 7`). But after 50, any ordinary composite will be divisible by an ordinary prime or by one of the exceptional 10-primes. I think we can prove this in general, for n-primes.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen It's not very hard to prove this.  All composite numbers that are n-prime must have only prime factors that are smaller than n.  We also know that no subset of their factors can have a product larger than n because our number would be divisible by that.  Thus every n-prime is either 2-prime or the product of 2 numbers less than n.  There are only a finite number of pairings of numbers less than n, thus there are only a finite number of composite n-prime numbers.  Hopefully that makes sense, I had to abbreviate to fit it in a comment.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen A simple modification on that proof can be used to prove that the upper bound on n-prime composites is n^2-1.

Comment: Actually `(n-1)^2` is a stronger upper bound.  Here is the proof: Any composite number can be represented as `a*b` where `a` and `b` are integers greater than 1.  If the larger one (lets call it `a`) is greater than n and is n-composite, ab is n-composite, because `x | a -> x | ab`, but if its n-prime then ab is still n-composite because `ab | a`.  Thus for ab to be n-prime a must be smaller than n.  Since the larger is smaller than n both must be smaller than n.  Since both a and b are smaller than n ab must be at most `(n-1)^2`.

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
n!a=not$any(n!)[x|x<-[n..a-1],mod a x<1]||n>a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08x0TYvv0QlMa9SI09RM7qipsJGNzpPTy9R1zBWJzc/RSFRocLGMLamJs8u8X9uYmaebUFRZl6JgoqCmaKh6X8A)

I define a nice recursive function `(!)`:

`n!a` checks if any factor of `a`, in the range `[n,a-1]`, is an `n-prime`. Then it negates the result. It also makes sure that `n>a`

Comment: [Here's a little bit of competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149150/56656)

Comment: @WheatWizard I was hoping someone would post the shorter solution :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

Thanks to Halvard Hummel for -2 bytes.

```python
f=lambda n,i:n==i or i>i%n>0<f(n+1,i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCoMwAAV3v@ItgqEZoqWLNPmR0iFi0z5onxJc/Po0Tq7H3a379lk0lJL8N/6mOUKWo7wnlgwGtgrunjpdektTUoUChRz1fnWD7a9mbIA1UxsexCHwFJy9OQMm1EPtn@UP)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda i,k:(i>k)<all(k%r for r in range(i,k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsMgEEX3OcUgCA5YaJpFQZqcxI0l2opmDJNsenpr2kV2n8d/b/3s70JDDaOt2S3P2UHUyag4JXy4nFWSDKEwMEQCdvTyqh0Q6wHLCW8a@gFNBytH2pWwJLdL24vfhCza0zw2Zklg9@ulU@31/XqYEAMEVVrd/CMJ6xc)

#### How it works

This takes two integers as input, **i** and **k**. First checks if **k ≥ i**. Then generates the range **[i, k)** and for each integer **N** in this range, checks if **N** is coprime to **k**. If both conditions are fulfilled, then **k** is an **i**-prime.

Comment: Can't you use `&` instead of `and` and `>=i` instead of `>i-1`?

Comment: @WheatWizard `>=i ` is still 4 bytes (because of the space).

Comment: @Neil If you change to `&` you don't need the space.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
εf≥⁰Ḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zWtEedSx81bni4o@v///9m/w1NAQ) or [see results up to 80](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9odXNr/yBtKHdTLG9gZuG4ozgw4oKBKeKApjIgMTP/zrVm4oml4oGw4biK//8).

Thanks to Leo for -1 byte.

### Explanation

```
εf≥⁰Ḋ  Inputs are n and k.
    Ḋ  Divisors of k.
 f     Keep those that are
  ≥⁰   at least n.
ε      Is the result a one-element list?
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>44</s> 37 bytes

```
function(a,n)a==n|a>n&all(a%%n:(a-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETPyVfspSYL8VAFhUD8Ei9LMbChbiWtJ@23x8aIMIfh8WZyiaHEpwwLT2LJCVII8qaL7GgcLXWdeEv7HrHEKYMFBhY4@P4ICC@tBlosOzCPzPfb7M1Wr2JQq2anarM/nZutOG4w2uSA8Ye@F@m/U6uuqbCRtXwA)

-7 bytes thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)

Returns `TRUE` if

- `a` is equal to `n` or (`a==n|`)
- `a` is greater than `n` *and* (`a>n&`) for every number *k* from `n` to `a-1`, `a` is not evenly divisible by *k* (`all(a%%n:(a-1))`)

Returns `FALSE` otherwise

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Great first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## J, 30 bytes

```
>:*(-{1=[:+/0=[:|/~]+i.@[)^:>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81Wz85KS0O32tA22kpb3wBI1ujXxWpn6jlEa8ZZ2VlxcaUmZ@QrGBooaMQq16XVKRloKmTqWRoo@DnpAUV1C4oyc1OLIYq09cHq0BT5leYmpRYp5KcpQNT@/w8A)

Takes starting value as the right argument and the value to check at the left argument.

I messed up originally and didn't account for left arguments less than the starting prime. I'm somewhat unhappy with the length of my solution now.

## Explanation

Let `x` be the left argument (the value to check) and `y` be the right argument (the starting prime).

```
>:*(-{1=[:+/0=[:|/~]+i.@[)^:>:
                          ^:>:  Execute left argument if x >= y
                     i.@[         Create range [0..x]
                   ]+             Add y to it (range now: [y..x+y])
                |/~               Form table of residues
            0=                    Equate each element to 0
          +/                      Sum columns
      1=                          Equate to 1
    -{                            Take the element at position x-y
>:*                             Multiply by result of x >= y
```

#### Notes

The element at position `x-y` is the result of primality testing for `x` (since we added `y` to the original range).

Multiplying by `x >: y` ensures that we get a falsey value (`0`) for `x` less than `y`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(n)(a)`. Returns a boolean.

```js
n=>p=(a,k=a)=>k%--a?p(a,k):a<n
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>p=(a,k=a)=>k%--a?p(a,k):a<n

for(n = 2; n <= 12; n++) {
  for(a = n, P = []; P.length < 31; a++) {
    f(n)(a) && P.push(a);
  }
  O.innerText += 'n=' + n + ': ' + P.join(',') + '\n';
}
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to H.PWiz's idea which was borrowed from [flawr's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149863/iterated-phi-sequence/149870#149870)*

```hs
n!a=[1]==[1|0<-mod a<$>[n..a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P08x0TbaMNYWSNQY2Ojm5qcoJNqo2EXn6eklxsb@z03MzLMtKMrMK1EpScxOVTA2VEnLzClJLdIwNFLUjDbU04v9DwA)

Ok since its been a while, and the only Haskell answer so far is 45 btyes, I decided to post my own answer.

### Explanation

This function checks that the only number between **n** and **a** that **a** is divisible by is **a** itself.

Now the definition only mentions **n**-primes smaller than **a**, so why are we checking all these extra numbers?  Won't we have problems when **a** is divisible by some **n**-composite larger than **n**?

We won't because if there is an **n**-composite larger than **n** it must be divisible by a smaller **n**-prime by definition.  Thus if it divides **a** so must the smaller **n**-prime.

If **a** is smaller than **n** `[n..a]` will be `[]` thus cannot equal `[1]` causing the check to fail.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```
rḍṛċ<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/o4Y7ehztnH@m2@X94udL//0Y6CmY6CuY6CoaGOgpG/w0tgSxTIAYKAikjAA)

This outputs `0` or `1` for "yes" and a positive integer greater than `1` for "no". This really stretches the "output two distinct values", so I've included a more reasonable 6 byte version:

```
rḍṛṖi<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/o4Y7ehztnP9w5LdPm/@HlSv//G@komOkomOsoGBrqKBj9N7QEskyBGCgIpIwA)

Outputs `0` for "yes, it is \$n\$-prime" and a positive integer for "no it is not \$n\$-prime". [+1 byte](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/o4c5pD3f0Ptw5O9XB5v/h5Ur//xvpKJjpKJjrKBga/je0BFKmQAwUMQUA) to use just `0` and `1`.

### How they work

```
rḍṛċ< - Main link. Takes n on the left and a on the right
r     - Range from n to a inclusive
  ṛ   - Right; Yield a
 ḍ    - For each element in the range, is it divisible by a?
    < - Is n < a?
   ċ  - Count the occurrences of (n < a) in the divisibility range
```

This works because in the range \$[n, a]\$, only one integer can be divisible by \$a\$ if \$a\$ is \$n\$-prime: \$a\$. Therefore, the range, after divisibility, would look like `[0, 0, 0, ..., 1]`. However, this doesn't check the condition that \$n\$ is the smallest \$n\$-prime, as `r` will generate a descending range if \$n < a\$. Therefore, we check that \$n < a\$ and count the occurrences of that (`1` or `0`) in the divisibility range. If \$n > a\$, there will be more than one `0` in the range, and if \$a\$ is not \$n\$-prime, but \$n < a\$, there will be more than `1` in the range.

If \$n = a\$, then `r` will yield an empty list and `ċ` will return `0`, no matter what the result of `<` is.

```
rḍṛṖi< - Main link. Takes n on the left and a on the right
r      - Range from n to a inclusive
  ṛ    - Right; Yield a
 ḍ     - For each element in the range, is it divisible by a?
   Ṗ   - Remove the final element, 1
     < - Is n < a?
    i  - Index of (n < a) or 0 if not found
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>23</s> <s>19</s> 14 bytes

```
b>=a&$&b%(a,b)
```

Shortest method is a port of [Mr. Xcoder's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149000/16766). Takes the smallest prime and the number to test as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/yc42UU1FLUlVI1EnSfP///9m/w1NAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 55 bytes

```
f(n,a,i){for(i=a;i-->n;)a%i||f(n,i)&&(i=0);return-1<i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BDoMwDATvvMJCAsXCSARuDfAXBE3llKaIwgl4O3Vaqd3jenbc57e@P0@rPHXEuNnnrLjpDOd56w12Ce97ODKmqRwKNPN1WWef65rNcbJf4NGxVxhtEUhkDyq0dxrJETfaANe6MpBlTDCty0vFMeIXnGZBrYqTcrjEBIwErhFsbAoDY11pSFPRtXrfXV1ikDj8/AlhC8oqwR3@y5CfthpAtI5kN6KJjvMN)

**53 bytes if multiple truthy return values are allowed:**

```
f(n,a,i){for(i=a;i-->n;)a%i||f(n,i)&&(i=0);return~i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1BDoIwEEX3nGJCQtMJQwKys8BdCFgzFStBWAFeHaea6F/@ef9Nl1277jis9tQS42ofk@a6NZxljTfYJrxt4ciolBxyNNNlXib/YrMf7Ge4t@w1RmsEElmDDu2NBnLEdWGAq6I0kKZMMC7zU8cx4hccJ0GtjpNTf44JGAlcLdhQ5waGqixAKdE1xba56oRB4vDzJ4QtaKsFd/gvQ37asgfROpLdgCbajzc)

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <sub><s>40</s></sub> <sub><s>34</s></sub> 37 bytes

```
[0p3Q]sf?se[dler%0=f1+dle>u]sudle>u1p
```

I would have included a TIO link, but TIO seems to be carrying a faulty distribution of `dc` seeing as how this works as intended on my system but the `Q` command functions erroneously on TIO. Instead, here is a link to a `bash` testing ground with a correctly functioning version of `dc`:

[Demo It!](http://tpcg.io/lFU7Hc)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 24 bytes

```apl
{⍵∊o/⍨1=+/¨0=o|⍨⊂o←⍺↓⍳⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71bH3V05es/6l1haKutf2iFgW1@DZDzqKspHyj/qHfXo7bJj3o3A9XV/v@vYagNZBsZairoKEDYxgaaCo96VyloIHE7ZuilAY1QMAIrNtAEAA)

**How?**

`⍳⍵` - `1` to `a`

`o←⍺↓` - `n` to `a`, save to `o`

`o|⍨⊂o` - modulo every item in `o` with every item in `o`

`0=` - check where it equals `0` (divides)

`+/¨` - sum the number of divisions

`1=` - if we have only one then the number is only divided by itself

`o/⍨` - so we keep these occurences

`⍵∊` - is `a` in that residual array?

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 20 bytes

```
L,2Dx@rBcB%B]b*!!A>*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx8ilwqHIKdlJ1Sk2SUtR0dFO6////6b/LQE)

```
L,   - Create a lambda function
     - Example arguments:  [5 9]
  2D - Copy below; STACK = [5 9 5]
  x  - Repeat;     STACK = [5 9 [9 9 9 9 9]]
  @  - Reverse;    STACK = [[9 9 9 9 9] 5 19] 
  r  - Range;      STACK = [[9 9 9 9 9] [5 6 7 8 9]]
  Bc - Zip;        STACK = [[9 5] [9 6] [9 7] [9 8] [9 9]]
  B% - Modulo;     STACK = [4 3 2 1]
  B] - Wrap;       STACK = [[4 3 2 1]]
  b* - Product;    STACK = [24]
  !! - Boolean;    STACK = [1]
  A  - Arguments;  STACK = [1 5 9]
  >  - Greater;    STACK = [1 1]
  *  - Product;    STACK = [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 27 bytes

```javascript
i=>f=n=>i==n||i>i%n&&f(n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQ0yQbURD1O@8iprHQLTL68u7zvTv8ocWXn28RPZNVMiafScgzkfTOnidxLoPMG1pUaVrSWvSCCgfCjmgD)

Port of my Python answer, takes input in currying syntax: `m(number)(first prime)`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES5, 34 Bytes

```
for(a=i=(p=prompt)();a%--i;);i<p()
```