# Iterated phi sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, kolmogorov-complexity, number-theory

Related: [Iterated phi(n) function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2550437).

Your challenge is to compute the iterated phi function:

```
f(n) = number of iterations of φ for n to reach 1.
```

Where `φ` is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Related [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A003434).

Here's the graph of it:

[image]

---

#### Rules:

Your goal is to output `f(n)` from `n=2` to `n=100`.

This is code-golf, so shortest code wins.

Here's the values you can check against:

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Fixed, and also added graph + values to check against. :-)

Comment: I've edited in the [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) tag, as this is essentially outputting a fixed value

Comment: [tags:kolmogorov-complexity] is correct in this case, though it is (probably) much shorter to implement the function. If you ask the question backwards (given the values, write a program printing the values) there will probably be no-one figure that out.

Comment: @user202729 Oh god, that sounds *very* complicated. Hm...

Comment: Which "that" are you referring to?

Comment: @user202729 The reverse engineering/question backwards.

Comment: @user202729 You think nobody would look up the values in the OEIS first thing?

Comment: Hm, if `f^-1(n)` returns the set of values such that `f(x) = n`, I wonder if this set is finite for all `n`.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ok, without OEIS lookup, it is hard. [A3434](http://oeis.org/A3434).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt First prove that there are finitely many values `x` such that `phi(x)` is a particular fixed number.

Comment: This is a nice challenge, but I think it would be better to just ask for a solution to implement `f(n)`, rather than run it on a range of fixed numbers. This also makes a difference between languages with ability to apply functions on ranges with less bytes (partly chameleon challenge?)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_rate), we have a lower bound on `φ(n)` on the order of `n/log log n`, so there's only a finite range in which a particular value of `f` can be achieved.

Comment: :P Are you implying I should change the challenge to give you an advantage? Regardless of how these rules are stated, some languages will have an advantage and some won't. @Uriel

Comment: Ah, nice find @MishaLavrov

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt not really, my language of choice can handle the wrapper pretty easily. But it feels like an overhead (somewhat redisual). Anyway, good challenge

Comment: Do we need to separate the numbers or is an output of `122323333434344534444545444545555545455645555655565646555656556656665656565656656757566756666667566` allowed?

Comment: @ovs they need to be separated somehow.

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

Thanks nimi for saving 1 byte!

```hs
f<$>[2..100]
f 1=0
f n=1+f(sum[1|1<-gcd n<$>[1..n]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxDkAwEADQ3VfcYCCi6ZnVj9ChKUWcS6Nsvt1hedNbXNomIiEzSGjzrm@UQq1tFgCN/mSDVSjStfd4Y1vPfgT@HyrF1payu5XBQDxWPiEHkscHcnOS2sf4Ag)

`sum[1|1<-gcd n<$>[1..n]]` gives `φ(n)` (Taken from [flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149870/71256),  thanks!)

`f` is a recursive function that calculates `1+φ(n)` if n is not `1`, and outputs `0` if `n` is `1`, as there are no more iterations to be taken to reach `1`

Finally `f<$>[2..100]` creates a list of `f` applied to each element of `[2..100]`

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
99:Q"@`_Zptq}x@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39LSKlDJISE@qqCksLbC4f9/AA)

#### Explanation

```
99:       % Push [1 2 ... 99]
Q         % Add 1 element-wise: gives [2 3 ... 100]
"         % For each k in that array
  @       %   Push k
  `       %   Do...while
    _Zp   %     Euler's totient function
     tq   %     Duplicate, subtract 1. This is the loop condition
  }       %   Finally (execute on loop exit)
  x       %     Delete
  @       %     Push latest k
          %   End (implicit)
          % End (implicit)
          % Display stack (implicit)
```

### Old version, 16 bytes

```
99:Qt"t_Zp]v&X<q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39LSKrBEqSQ@qiC2TC3CpvD/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
99:       % Push [1 2 ... 99]
Q         % Add 1 element-wise: gives [1 2 ... 100]
t"        % Duplicate. For each (i.e. do the following 100 times)
  t       %   Duplicate
  _Zp     %   Euler's totient function, element-wise
]         % End
v         % Concatenate vertically. Gives a 100×100 matrix
&X<       % Row index of the first minimizing entry for each column.
          % The minimum is guaranteed to be 1, because the number of
          % iterations is more than sufficient.
q         % Subtract 1. Display stack (implicit)
```

Comment: The values outputted are off by one, I think [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39LSKrBEqSQ@qiC2TC3CpvD/fwA "MATL – Try It Online") corrects that (but I've never used MATL before so...)

Comment: Check the end of my post. It provides the expected output, to which you are off by one on each.

Comment: The first 5 values outputted by your current answer are `2 3 3 4 3`, when the challenge says they should be `1 2 2 3 2`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing and SimplyBeautifulArt Ah, I see. Thanks! Corrected now

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>70 69</s> 68 bytes

The function `(\n->sum[1|1<-gcd n<$>[1..n]])` is the totient function, which we repeatedly apply in the anonymous function. Thanks @laikoni for -1 byte!

EDIT: I just found out @xnor used this exact totient function in a [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83634/24877).

```hs
length.fst.span(>1).iterate(\n->sum[1|1<-gcd n<$>[1..n]])<$>[2..100]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rcwxDoAgDADAr3RwgIHGOiMfUQaiqERsjNTNv2P8g9tNt4Wyx5xrNSZHXmXDpQiWM7BypDFJvIJENbJx5T4GesiadZqBbeMGQmTv9ccOkdrW1yMkhh7OK7FAA7@cLw)

Comment: This is pretty short for not having a totient builtin!

Comment: @LuisMendo H.PWiz found a solution that is [even shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149874/24877)!

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s>  8 bytes

```
³ḊÆṪƬ>1S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5oc7ug63Pdy56tgaO8Pg//8B)

-1 byte thanks to HyperNeutrino!

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder!

-1 byte thanks to Dennis

### How it works

```
³ḊÆṪƬ>1S - Main link. No arguments
³        - Yield 100
 Ḋ       - Dequeue. Creates the list [2, 3 ... 99, 100]
    Ƭ    - Until the following produces a repeated value, collecting each loop:
  ÆṪ     -   Totient of each
     >1  - Greater than one?
       S - Sum the columns
```

Comment: @dylnan All three answers output the list of `f(n)` from `2` to `100`, and the question doesn't mention input, so I think this is the correct version

Comment: @dylnan The challenge asks to output `f` for `n=2` to `n=100`, not just one value.

Comment: You're right, I had read the beginning of the challenge and didn't read the rules part clearly

Comment: And with regards to the code, would it be possible to use `#` in this case? Something like [this](https://tio.run/##ARkA5v9qZWxsef//w4bhuarDkMS/TArDh8KzI///) (which clearly doesn't work but written by someone who understands the syntax clearly!)

Comment: @dylnan Possibly, but as we're generating a fixed list, to apply over each element, `€` is usually better than `#`.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Aww, but now I have to rewrite the explanation :P Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Do you mind if I "take" that as a golf?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That was a golfing suggestion, so go ahead and edit that in

Comment: @Dennis or anyone else: is it possible in a `#` loop to return a list of the truthy values found instead of the list of indices which evaluate to a truthy value?

Comment: @dylnan There is a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32533/jelly) specifically about asking questions about Jelly, and another about [learning Jelly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57815/jelly-hypertraining), just to let you know, as you seem interested in the language.

Comment: It's not that different from your original code. `ÐĿ` loops until `ÆṪ` returns a list of 99 ones, `>1` maps all non-**1** values to **1**, then `S` sums, effectively counting the number of non-**1**'s in each column.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, I'm starting to understand it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>50</s> <s>29</s> 25 bytes

Look 'ma, no built-in totient!

*4 bytes saved thanks to @H.PWiz*

```apl
{⍵=1:0⋄1+∇+/1=⍵∨⍳⍵}¨1+⍳99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE6of9W61NbQyeNTdYqj9qKNdW9/QFij0qGPFo97NQEbtoRVA8d7Nlpb//wMA)

**How?**

*Apparently I went for the longer (and harder) totient formula first. See revisions history.*

`⍳⍵` - `1` to `n`

`⍵∨` - gcd with `n`

`1=` - equal to 1?

`+/` - sum 'em all

This is the totient. All the rest is wrapper for the counting (`1+∇`) and applying on the range `2..100` (`¨1+⍳99`).

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 44 bytes

```
(i=-1;#+1//.x_:>EulerPhi[++i;x];i)&~Array~99
```

-10 bytes from @Misha Lavrov
-2 bytes from @user202729

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7XyPTVtfQWlnbUF9fryLeys61NCe1KCAjM1pbO9O6ItY6U1OtzrGoKLGyztLyf0BRZl6JQ9p/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>115</s> ... <s>104</s> 99 bytes

Hard-coding might be shorter, but let's try a purely mathematical approach.

```js
f=n=>n>97?6:(P=(n,s=0)=>k--?P(n,s+(C=(a,b)=>b?C(b,a%b):a<2)(n,k)):s>1?1+P(k=s):1)(k=n+2)+' '+f(-~n)

console.log(f())
```

Comment: Hard-coding is 90 bytes ([pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/thkJnt0y))

Comment: @HermanLauenstein Nicely done.

Answer (score 4):

## J REPL, 23 bytes

```
<:#@(5&p:^:a:)"0|2+i.99
```

I haven’t checked, but this probably works in regular J if you define it as a noun (I golfed this on my phone on the REPL).

Built-ins, yo.

I’d say that there are *at least* 2-3 bytes to shave off (off-by-one because of the way `a:` works, having to use `|` as a noop, etc.).

Comment: `+/*<:5&p:^:a:2+i.99`  for 19 bytes
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19BW1/LxspUrcAqzirRykg7U8/S8v9/AA)

Comment: For future reference, you can aso use `"+` instead of `"0`, so it could equally become `<:#@(5&p:^:a:)"+i.99`

Comment: 16 bytes with `+/1<a:5&p:2+i.99`

Comment: @ miles : Can you explain the use of `a:` in your code? How does it work instead of `^:`?

Comment: @GalenIvanov `(5&p:)^:a: m` can be done as `a: 5&p: m` using the other definition of `&` when a dyad is bonded with a noun and then called dyadically.

Comment: @miles Thank you! Now I see it's explained in the vocabulary too.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 80 bytes

```python
n,_=r=2,0;exec'r+=r[sum(k/n*k%n>n-2for k in range(n*n))]+1,;print r[n];n+=1;'*99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRDkAgGAbQV@nGUBl1Zy0vYmZmoTWf9svG0@ec@KXjgs4ZcrZkteyMe91akrA03s9ZhRY8FBjQ6O0iFpgHowW7q8BR15NQ0kTySIxGTAbCKlPyvs/5Bw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 82 bytes

```python
l=0,1
exec"n=len(l);p=2\nwhile n%p:p+=1\nl+=l[p-1]+l[n/p]-n%4%3/2,;print l[n];"*99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjRCkAwFAbge08htcKIjRvWeRJ2pRV1@p20wtOP7/KTN@4nbEpMfWOy8IStAHFAyZUTsivu/eCQQ8ksmswK1sSLtMZrXtCJb6FGNXS2cXIdiPm/3hX1NKX0AQ)

This uses the observations that:

- `f(a*b) = f(a) + f(b) - 1`, except the `-1` is omitted if `a` and `b` are both even
- `f(p) = f(p-1) + 1` when `p` is prime, with `f(2)=1`

These imply that if `n` has prime factorization `n = 2**a * 3**b * 5**c * 7**d * 11**e * ...`, then `f(n) = max(a,1) + b + 2*c + 2*d + 3*e + ...`, where each `p>2` in the factorization contributes `f(p-1)`.

I'm not sure if these continue to hold past `n=100`, but if they do, they give a way to define and calculate `f` without using `φ`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 17 bytes

```
mö←LU¡Sȯṁε⌋ḣtḣ100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fwtkdtE3xCDy0MPrH@4c7Gc1sf9XQ/3LG4BIgNDQz@/wcA)

**Edit**: +7 bytes for actually mapping the function over the range that was asked for, before it was only the function computing [A003434](https://oeis.org/A003434).

#### Explanation

The following computes [A003434](https://oeis.org/A003434):

```
←LU¡S(ṁ(ε⌋))ḣ -- takes a number as input, for example: 39
   ¡          -- iterate the following function on the input: [39,24,8,4,2,1,1,1..]
    S(     )ḣ --   with itself (x) and the range [1..x]..
      ṁ(  )   --   ..map and sum the following
        ε⌋    --     0 if gcd not 1 else 1
  U           -- longest unique prefix: [39,24,8,4,2,1]
 L            -- length: 6
←             -- decrement: 5
```

The `m(....)ḣ100` part just map that function over the range [2..100], not sure how I missed that part before :S

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 110 bytes

```powershell
$a=,0*101;2..100|%{$i=$_;for($z=$j=0;++$j-lt$i;$z+=$k-eq1){for($k=$j;$j%$k-or$i%$k;$k--){}};($a[$i]=$a[$z]+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrRCgIhFAV/5iysmYu318v9klhiH4x0BcuCQPPbzXqaYZh7erv8vLkYe8cmR3sgS3xaFrL2M1V4wYWvKc8ogiCWtUYw8QXPKFqwG/cgVf/HPg5GmEZMGX6QhxpVW@MZ2xl@lR/Kqkm13r8)

Mathematical approach.

Actually, looking through it, very similar to the [C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149936/42963), but developed independently. Creates an array of `0`s, loops from `2` to `100`, then calculates `phi` using the `gcd` formulation. The part in parens at the end both saves the result into `$a` for the next go-round, and places a copy on the pipeline, which results in the implicit output.

---

#### PowerShell, 112 bytes

```powershell
"122323333434344534444545444545555545455645555655565646555656556656665656565656656757566756666667566"-split'(.)'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYZBCoAwDAT/0kv1oGCbpi8qKAQsVvD5cRN0NzObfj7tGnsTUQ1bSjllhKxUAIy6Lb7sPztM30Kw8RdXS8UaFtuwjC7HHad1jqov)

Hard-coded. Ho-hum. <s>Shorter than I could get a mathematical approach by about 10-15 bytes.</s>

Comment: I wonder whether you actually need a separator, as all the numbers are single digits:)

Comment: Can you show us your mathematical approach? It looks much more interesting certainly :P

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Luckily enough, I was able to look at it with fresh eyes this morning and golf the mathematical approach below the hard-coded approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 49 bytes

```
00000000: 5d88 0511 0020 0003 ab2c 024e ff64 e8a3  ].... ...,.N.d..
00000010: 379f 956b f05d 206c 0545 7274 743a b876  7..k.] l.Ertt:.v
00000020: 2267 27f9 9f4d 9b9d fc85 e7e6 994d 6eb0  "g'..M.......Mn.
00000030: 2b                                       +
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY47DgIxDER7TjGioQBZXufjhJ4SbkCxJgkFnwIB11@CgJ4njYuR5sn2MDvX4@MyTfxljVBSAodhALNwP@wwmhzA4itaix41jQ7YUwc9K9pRIZp9DEN3OM0NOURD41AgHPs8@AAV9VDvRljSCCjRifY40@Z2v6/p@XVId4hEhWjLyM0XZMsF7ZACqtaInHsXqzEwPy6ItvRhe/394d4Ow38sp@kF)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
n=2
exec"print len(bin(n))-3+n%2-~n%9/8-(0x951a5fddc040419d4005<<19>>n&1);n+=1;"*99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P8/WiCu1IjVZqaAoM69EISc1TyMpM08jT1NT11g7T9VIty5P1VLfQlfDoMLS1DDRNC0lJdnAxMDE0DLFxMDA1MbG0NLOLk/NUNM6T9vW0FpJy9Ly/38A)

Combines a heuristic estimate with a hardcoded constant that corrects each estimate as either `-0` or `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 98 bytes

```
1,2,<?=join(',',str_split(unpack('H*','##3444E4DEEDEEUUEEVEUVUVVFUVVUfVfVVVVVegWVgVffgV')[1]))?>,6
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fUMdIx8beNis/M09DXUddp7ikKL64ICezRKM0ryAxOVtD3UMLKK6sbGxiYuJq4uLqCkShoa6uYa6hYaFhYW5AHJoWlhYGAqnp4WHpYWlp6WHqmtGGsZqa9nY6Zv//AwA)

I packed all digits into a binary string.
After unpacking it, converting it to a an array and then mergin the array again, i only had to prepend the 1,2 and append the 6 as those wouldnt fit or caused a control code to appear.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 47 bytes

```
map {($_,{+grep 1==* gcd $_,^$_}...1)-1},2..200
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7r/E/N7FAoVpDJV6nWju9KLVAwdDWVkshPTlFASgUpxJfq6enZ6ipa1irY6SnZ2Rg8F9TLys/M09DSUdBSVOvOLHyPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
тL¦ε[DNs#sÕ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//YpPPoWXntka7@BUrFx@e@v8/AA)

**Explanation**

```
тL¦           # push range [2 ... 100]
   ε          # apply to each
    [         # start a loop
     D        # duplicate the current number
      N       # push the loop iteration counter
       s      # swap one copy of the current number to the top of the stack
        #     # if true, break the loop
         s    # swap the second copy of the current number to the top of the stack
          Õ   # calculate eulers totient
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 112 bytes

```c
a[101];f(i,j,k,t){for(a[i=1]=0;i++<100;printf("%d ",a[i]=a[t]+1))for(t=j=0;++j<i;t+=k==1)for(k=j;j%k||i%k;k--);}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
a[101];
f(i,j,k,t){
    for(a[1]=0,i=2;i<=100;i++) {   // initialize
        for(t=j=0;++j<i;t+=k==1)   // count gcd(i, j) == 1 (t = phi(i))
            for(k=j;j%k||i%k;k--); // calculate k = gcd(i, j)
        printf("%d ",a[i]=a[t]+1); // print and store results
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsMgEEWvUgIBZRSc9WROIi7EYhmHpiW4a3p2a7r87z34xT9KGSNHDJioGnHNqev2U1@HyVEYEwcSgA1DoPche69mWe@3xU2bOMeeAK298s5ttgBtE@rAyox/rtyorXqesiqp95a@45llN/PFXOMH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Alumin](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Alumin), 87 bytes

```
hhhhhdadtqdhcpkkmzyhqkhwzydqhhwdrdhhhwrysrshhwqdrybpkshehhhwrysrarhcpkksyhaydhehycpkkmr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxRCoAwDEPPOo0QqZO1VUZ3@ToF8xN4j6Qcd93PTL5BwaXg2kTqCKqwj4CSHYbpu4Wbz1ZYLE2c20@LfTMPlsDE8Z1Y5gM)

### Explanation

```
hhhhhdadt      CONSTANT 100

RANGE FROM 100 to 0
q
  dhc
p

REMOVE 0 AND 1
kk

OVER EACH ELEMENT...
m
  zyh
  q
    kh
    wzyd
    q
      DUPLICATE TOP TWO ELEMENTS...
      hhwdrdhhhwrysrshhw
      GCD...
      qdryb
    p
    ks
    he
    hhhw
    ry
    s
    rarhc
  p
  IS IT ONE? IF SO TERMINATE (FIXPOINT)
  kksyhaydhehyc
p
kk
m
REVERSE THE VALUES
r
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 38 bytes (not competitive)

```
.e-+1sl+1kb_jC"Éõ4ÕYHø\\uÊáÛ÷â¿"3
```

[Try it on the Pyth Herokuapp](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.e-%2B1sl%2B1kb_jC%22%0F%C3%89%C3%B5%C2%854%C3%95Y%16H%C3%B8%5C%5Cu%C2%91%07%C3%8A%C3%A1%C3%9B%C3%B7%C3%A2%C2%BF%223&debug=0), because it doesn't work on TIO for whatever reason.

I have no doubt the explicit Pyth solution is smaller, but I wanted to see how small I could get the code by compressing the sequence, and learn Pyth I guess. This uses the fact that an upper bound of the sequence is `log2(n)+1`.

### Explanation

```
.e-+1sl+1kb_jC"Éõ4ÕYHø\\uÊáÛ÷â¿"3
             C"Éõ4ÕYHø\\uÊáÛ÷â¿"   interpret string as base 256 integer
            j                   3  convert to array of base 3 digits
           _                       invert sequence (original had leading 0s)
.e                                 map with enumeration (k=index, b=element)
       +1k                                   k+1
     sl                            floor(log(   ))
   +1                                             +1
  -       b                                         -b
```

I got the compressed string via `Ci_.e+1-sl+1ksb"122323333434344534444545444545555545455645555655565646555656556656665656565656656757566756666667566"3`, which is just the opposite of the code above with a few type conversions.

Comment: Why noncompeting?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt didn't really mean noncompeting in the formal sense; edited the title to make that more clear

Answer (score 0):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 41 bytes

```
“ ‽W3>€þΣÌιZ§Á HgüυH§u·β}Bā€ΣNπáÂUõÚ,3“8B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv9vaG0y///igJwg4oC9VzM@4oKsw77Oo8OMzrlawqfDgSBIZ8O8z4VIwqd1wrfOsn1CxIHigqzOo07PgMOhw4JVw7XDmiwz4oCcOEL//w)

Literally completely hardcoded... I actually took the sequence above, stripped everything that wasn't a number, interpreted it as base 8, then turned it into Ohm's built-in base 255 number representation. That's what the quotes do. Then, the program simply turns that into base 8 again.